# 'C:\documents\TheHistoryDB.accdb' is not a valid path

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, ms-access

Trying to write some history to an access datebase but I keep getting an error stating that `the path is invalid`. I'm using a connection string and I'm getting it from the wizard itself. Copy and Paste. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class theControls

'The History Database Connection String
Dim theHistoryDatabaseConn As New OleDbConnection

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles theAddressBar.KeyDown
    'Navigate to Webpage stated in theAddressBar
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Enter Then
        theBrowser.Navigate(theAddressBar.Text)
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub goForward_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles goForward.Click
    theBrowser.GoForward()
End Sub

Private Sub goBack_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles goBack.Click
    theBrowser.GoBack()
End Sub

Private Sub theBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles theBrowser.DocumentCompleted

    'Set Tab Text to current web page
    Form1.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = theBrowser.Url.Host.ToString

    'The History

    theHistoryDatabaseConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\bin\Debug\TheHistoryDB.accdb"


    Dim theCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO TheHistory ([Site]) VALUES (theBrowser.URL.Host)", theHistoryDatabaseConn)

    theCommand.Parameters.Add("@Site", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = theBrowser.Url.Host.ToString

    Try
        theHistoryDatabaseConn.Open()
        theCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        theHistoryDatabaseConn.Close()

    End Try
    theHistoryDatabaseConn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub theBrowser_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles theBrowser.ProgressChanged

    'Status Bar Text
    Label1.Text = theBrowser.StatusText.ToString
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is `C:\documents\theHistoryDB.accdb` the correct path? 'Cause using folders directly off of the drive root is really poor practice. Try `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` instead.

Comment: Yes it is. I didn't want to paste in the full path. The full path is not directly off the root,

Comment: so Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData = "path"?

Comment: It's an expression that evaluates into a path. You can put your database there during app installation.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question says "C:\documents\TheHistoryDB.accdb" but your code is showing "|DataDirectory|\bin\Debug\TheHistoryDB.accdb". Are you sure you have your path correct?

Normally the folder used for documents would be something like "C:\Users\myusername\Documents". Not saying C:\documents doesn't exist on your computer, but just commenting that's an odd place for it.

```
Dim theCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO TheHistory ([Site]) VALUES (theBrowser.URL.Host.ToString)", theHistoryDatabaseConn)
```

This is unrelated, but it doesn't look right to me. It looks like you're trying to access an object, but you're inside a string. I'm a C# guy, not VB. It just looks fishy to me. Also, why are you catching the Exception and immediately re-throwing it? Doesn't it kind of defeat the purpose?

Comment: Definitely that sql is wrong. Should just be `@Site` instead of that control reference.

Comment: The path was modified. I didn't want to paste the entire thing. But yes it is correct. I do not think I have the SQL statement wrong becuase i'm using this in another example where i'm doing something similar

Comment: @mwilson I'm not sure how you expect us to be able to spot the answer if you're not providing what you're doing to generate the error. You have two different paths. One you mentioned in the title of your question, the other in the code block. What are you using?

Comment: that is exactly why i'm confused. my connection string is this:

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\bin\Debug\TheHistoryDB.accdb

and the actual path is C:\Users\mwilson\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myBrowser\myBrowser\bin\Debug\TheHistoryDB.accdb

I don't have a full path anywhere in my code but the error message calls it out specifically.

Comment: I have tried modifying the connection string but it didn't work. What is the significance of |DataDirectory|?

In the example that I created (seperate from that works fine) I don't have that in my connection string

Comment: You may find connectionstrings.com useful. I found this which explains datadirectory by googling: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/

Answer (score 0):

If you have database in the same folder with app, better use `startuppath`

```
theHistoryDatabaseConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\TheHistoryDB.accdb"
```